How to Sum a Double value Jolt Transform v0.1.1
I am not able to find a solution for this transformation, i have a input JSON, model below, and i need to sum the values of "totalValue" tag.
Input JSON
{
  "id": "ec4f9fbd-f595-4d03-a514-2133aabdd138",
  "listOfOrderItem": [
    {
      "erpReferenceKey": null,
      "totalValue": 60.78,
      "discontValue": 0,
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "erpReferenceKey": null,
      "totalValue": 28.66,
      "discontValue": 0,
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "erpReferenceKey": null,
      "totalValue": 48.84,
      "discontValue": 0,
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}

Expected output
{
  "Sum": 138,28
}


Your Sum above doesnt take in consideration all TotalValue from json and it should be 138.28.
Assuming that is what you need, the following should work:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "listOfOrderItem": {
        "*": {
          "totalValue": "totalValues"
        }
      }
    }
  }
 ,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Sum": "=doubleSum(@(1,totalValues))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "totalValues": ""
    }
  }
]

Hope that helps.
